# How to update document from different collection that has the same uid? Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update the location field of each document inside the subcollection family. If the family document "uid" is equal to users document "uid", I want to update the location in family and assign it to the location from users.

The document in users:

[image: This is the users document.]

The document in family :

[image: This the family document]

Here is my failed attempt :

```
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;

  Future<void> updateFamilyLocation() {
    users.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((docu) {
        users
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('family')
            .get()
            .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
            if (doc["uid"] == docu["uid"]) {

              //update family location
              return users
                  .doc(uid)
                  .collection("family")
                  .doc()
                  .update({
                    "location": docu["location"],
                  })
                  .then((value) => print("Family is updated"))
                  .catchError(
                      (error) => print("Failed to update family: $error"));
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

According to the error, it says :

W/Firestore( 7827): (22.0.1) [WriteStream]: (6fdbd71) Stream closed with status: Status{code=NOT_FOUND, description=Requested entity was not found., cause=null}.
I/flutter ( 7827): Failed to update family: [cloud_firestore/not-found] Some requested document was not found.

Comment: what I can see from the image that you put is that "users" and "family" are two different collections, and firebase can only take data from a single collection, and my guess is that is why you are getting the ```NOT_FOUND``` error, you can find more information about how firebase query the collections in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474876/query-data-in-multiple-collections)

Comment: @Robertocd_98 Oh I see, so is it not doable then? Based on the post, I need to execute two reads and I have done that in my code above.

Comment: yes you are right, after looking more carefully at the error and you code I think that the issue is in the ```.doc()``` when you try to update the family collection, according to the documentation of Firebase you need to use the ```update()``` method, here is the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) to the official documentation. Please let me know if this help you

Comment: @Robertocd_98 I've figured out that my doc was not specific enough since doc() supposed to have id value in it in order to update it. So I need to get the document id for each document in the family collection first and pass it to the above function.

Comment: @kayla If you figured out the solution, could you share it in an answer for the rest of us? Thanks!