# Swift + Firestore: How to fetch related objects

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I have this model in Swift

```swift
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import FirebaseFirestore

struct Tweet: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var content: String
    var ownerId: String
    var owner: UserProfile
    var likes: Int
    @ServerTimestamp var createdAt: Timestamp?
}
```

and it's stored in Firestore collection "tweets":

```json
tweets: {
    [
        "ds4a65d4a65sd46das65d4": {
            "content" : "safsafds",
            "createdAt" : "...",
            "id" : "sdfsdfsd",
            "likes" : 0,
            "ownerId" : "123",
            "owner" : {
                 "bio": "aaasdasdassa",
                 "username": "asdasd",
                 "profileImage": "aaa",
                 "userId": "123",
             },
        }, ... 
    ]
}
```

When I fetch all tweets, I get the information normally, with the owner data. but the owner data could be old. say that the user has changed his profile image, or username...etc, so the tweets owners data could be not up-to-date.

So, assuming that we want to remove the owner field from the tweet model, and keep the ownerId.

### How to fetch all the tweets with the owners' data using the following model?

```swift
struct Tweet: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
        
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var content: String
    var ownerId: String
    // var owner: UserProfile   <-- THIS IS REMOVED
    var likes: Int
    @ServerTimestamp var createdAt: Timestamp?
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you can do dynamically in your fetch call. It sounds like you need to actually restructure your data on the server.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are trying to achieve is to update the owner data in the Tweet Collection. So, you are trying to query your Tweet collection and the referenced Owner collection at the same time. And that involves updating/ restructuring the data on the server side. And that is not feasible.

Firestore does not have the concept of server-side joins or projections across collections. Each query or document read can only take data from a single collection, or from all collections that have the same name with collection group queries. If you need to load data from two collections, you'll need at least two reads.

You can also refer to a similar [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474876/query-data-in-multiple-collections) case.

Comment: This is not answering the question.

Comment: Please find the above updated answer.